# Javascript - XMLHttpRequest receive null

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cross-origin-read-blocking

In chrome dev tools on the **network tab** I can see the **200 request**.

The problem is that I receive **null** on my response and the following error message

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response

```
function submit(id,player){

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var guess = document.getElementById(id).value

    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
            console.log(http.response)
        }
    }

    http.open("GET", "https://www.myEndPoint.com, true);
    http.responseType="json"
    http.send();

}
```

Comment: You have to add CORS annotation in the service class (Cross origin exception), check the below link https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: @ArunPrasat, thank you. I don't have access to the server, this is a challenge I need to do for a job. So for what I understand the problem is in the server side correct?

Comment: Client-side JS cannot request content from other servers unless the server specifically allows this. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS (there's two common solutions: use a cors proxy or route the request through your server)

Comment: Yes, correct Since the UI and the api have different hostname it won't allow. It will throw CORS exception. Try to add the CORS annotation in API or deploy both UI & API with same host name it will work.

Comment: @ArunPrasat - The error says CORB, not CORS

Comment: You've said `http.responseType="json"` but the response isn't JSON. Possibly this is because you also have a CORS error. You should quote all the error messages thrown by your code.

Comment: @Quentin, thanks, I have installed a chrome plugin for cors error

Answer (score 0):

CORB is a Chromium-specific security feature.

See: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/services/network/cross_origin_read_blocking_explainer.md

Specially:

> When CORB decides that a response needs to be CORB-protected, the response is modified as follows:
>
> - The response body is replaced with an empty body.
> - The response headers are removed.

Does any of these points apply to your endpoint?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes the response is null as for the response headers  -----Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,content-type,x-clientdetails,x-goog-authuser,x-goog-encode-response-if-executable,x-javascript-user-agent,x-requested-with
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE

Comment: On firefox i get this error ---- (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Comment: Don't know if this is the problem, but you are missing the closing quote mark in the url => http.open("GET", "https://www.myEndPoint.com, true);